# for windows 10 lock screen, is there any way to remove the comments/quips/quotes?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I enjoy the windows 10 new login screen, where a new background photograph is used daily. However I would like to get rid of the fortune cookie-type quips from microsoft (or whoever), usually tangentially related to the photograph (eg for the 11/6 image of rocks stacking, it says "your points stack up quick"). I wonder if there is some way to turn this setting off, perhaps a registry hack?

Comment: I've never seen this :o - Perhaps there's an application listed in `settings > personalisation > lock screen` that can show you info on the lock screen.

Comment: "However I would like to get rid of the fortune cookie-type quips from microsoft (or whoever), " - Its an all or nothing feature.  You can either use Windows Spotlight and deal with the quips, or disable Windows Spotlight and not deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for soemthing similar, so a little late, but for the next one, check [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hide-spotlight-lockscreen-tips-but-keep-rotation/b1cbb0d2-ed17-4b0f-8abc-7f04267d9ff6):

- Open Settings.
- Click on personalization.
- Click on lock screen.
- In the Background drop-down menu, select Picture or Slideshow.
- Turn off the Get fun facts, tips, and more from Windows and Cortana on your lock screen toggle switch.
- Then you can change the background back to Windows Spotlight.